# How to auto add a field in django admin model calculating age

Tags: python, django

is it possible to add an **age** field that is auto filled in the runtime based on another **date of birth** field at the django admin interface, i added a screenshot trying to explain more what i mean
[image]

my models.py

```
class FamilyMember(models.Model):
   transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   family_group = models.ForeignKey(FamilyGroup,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True,
                                blank=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
   date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
   relationship = models.ForeignKey(Relationship, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   dependant_child_age_range = models.ForeignKey(DependantChildAgeRange,
                                            null=True,
                                            blank=True,
                                            on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   care_percentage = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
    null=True, blank=True, validators=[
        MaxValueValidator(100),
    ])
   income = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,
                            decimal_places=2,
                            null=True,
                            blank=True)
 rent_percentage = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
     null=True, blank=True, validators=[
        MaxValueValidator(100),
    ])
```

admin.py

```
class FamilyMemberInline(admin.TabularInline):


def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    action = request.META['PATH_INFO'].strip('/').split('/')[-1]
    if action == 'change':
        transaction_id = request.META['PATH_INFO'].strip('/').split('/')[-2]
        if db_field.name == "family_group":
            kwargs["queryset"] = FamilyGroup.objects.filter(transaction=transaction_id)
    return super(FamilyMemberInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)



model = FamilyMember
extra = 0
def sufficient_info_provided (self, obj):
    return obj.sufficient_information_provided
sufficient_info_provided.boolean = True



readonly_fields = ['sufficient_info_provided',]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override your inline's [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method to [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) the queryset with the calculation. The annotation will add an `age` attribute to each object in the queryset.

Then as you can see in the [`ModelAdmin.list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) documentation, you can include a string representing a `ModelAdmin` method that accepts one argument, the model instance. Inline's work in the same way but you must include the method in `ModelAdmin.readonly_fields`.

Putting it all together:

```
class FamilyMemberInline(admin.TabularInline):
    ...
    fields = (..., 'get_age')
    readonly_fields = ('get_age',)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return (
            super().get_queryset(request)
            .annotate(age=...)
        )

    def get_age(self, instance):
        return instance.age
```

Comment: This is not op. Just curious: will the age box update during the "enter date of birth" time or after you save the instance and open it again? Thanks!

Comment: @ha-neul it will only update after you save the instance.

Comment: cant we make this age updated before saving the process ? is it even possible in the admin page?

Comment: @AbdullaOsama it would require custom javascript

Comment: @bdoubleu im a bit confused 
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return (
            super().get_queryset(request)
            .annotate(age=...), what should i replace in age= ?

Comment: Take a look at [`TruncYear`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncYear)